# Powershell Get-ItemProperty is returning 1 extra character to registry values

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

**Contents of test.ps1:**

```
Set-Location HKLM:
$RegistryKeys = (Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VMSMP\Parameters\NicList)
foreach ($Key in $RegistryKeys){
    if ((Get-ItemProperty $Key).FriendlyName -like "*Corp*") {
        Write-Host "Found Switch in $Key"
        $SwitchName = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $Key).SwitchName
        $PortName = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $Key).PortName
        Write-Host $SwitchName
        Write-Host $PortName
    }
    else{}
}
```

**Output** (I ran it 4 times in quick succession to make an **emphasis** on the weird extra character being added to the returned values):

```
Found Switch in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VMSMP\Parameters\NicList\03BDF338-4BC5-4896-8C40-55C91DEBB50D
D00D57C1-8FE2-447F-ABBD-B672CA2683CCø
D5BD78A2-543F-4F15-9FA6-729F62AE09A3ø
Found Switch in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VMSMP\Parameters\NicList\03BDF338-4BC5-4896-8C40-55C91DEBB50D
D00D57C1-8FE2-447F-ABBD-B672CA2683CCø
D5BD78A2-543F-4F15-9FA6-729F62AE09A3ø
Found Switch in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VMSMP\Parameters\NicList\03BDF338-4BC5-4896-8C40-55C91DEBB50D
D00D57C1-8FE2-447F-ABBD-B672CA2683CCø
D5BD78A2-543F-4F15-9FA6-729F62AE09A3ø
Found Switch in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VMSMP\Parameters\NicList\03BDF338-4BC5-4896-8C40-55C91DEBB50D
D00D57C1-8FE2-447F-ABBD-B672CA2683CCø
D5BD78A2-543F-4F15-9FA6-729F62AE09A3ø
Found Switch in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VMSMP\Parameters\NicList\03BDF338-4BC5-4896-8C40-55C91DEBB50D
D00D57C1-8FE2-447F-ABBD-B672CA2683CCm
D5BD78A2-543F-4F15-9FA6-729F62AE09A3m
```

Whats with the extra characters being added to the registry entries? The information being returned is correct except for that extra garbage character. Sometimes its o,m,s,?, but always seems to be one character only (sometimes it doesnt add extra characters).

Boggled.....

Comment: What are the data types of the value that you're trying to get back?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you're getting the value to a multi-string key, and those funny characters are the string separators.  I don't have the `VMSMP` key on my computer to verify my theory, though.